# Tool to include SVG files into other SVG files

Tags: command-line, svg

I have a bunch of SVG files that contain `<image>` tags which link to other SVG files.

I'd like to replace these `<image>` tags with the contents of the files they are linked to. In other words, directly include the SVG code into the master SVG file, instead of linking to outside dependencies.

I can do this manually, using a text editor, replacing each `<image>` tag with a `<g>` tag, adding `transform="translate()"` attribute and copying and pasting code from the linked file. However, given the number of files I need to edit, that approach is completely impractical. Is there a command line tool that does that automatically?